# sizeof with a type or variable

Tags: c, coding-style, sizeof

Recently saw someone commending another user on their use of sizeof var instead of sizeof(type). I always thought that was just a style choice. Is there any significant difference? As an example, the lines with f and ff were considered better than the lines with g and gg:

```
 typedef struct _foo {} foo;

 foo *f = malloc(count * sizeof f);
 foo *g = malloc(sizeof(foo) * count);

 foo **ff = malloc(count * sizeof *ff);
 foo **gg = malloc(sizeof(foo*) * count);
```

In my opinion, the first set is just a matter of style. But in the second pair of lines, the extra second * can easily be confused for a multiplication.

Comment: You have a bug in your first `malloc` line - it should be `sizeof *f`.  The general pattern is `somevar = malloc(count * sizeof *somevar)`.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(foo[count]))` works as well

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If the type of the variable is changed, the sizeof will not require changing if the variable is the argument, rather than the type.

Regarding @icepack's comment: the possibility or likelihood of change for type vs. variable name is not the issue. Imagine the variable name is used as the the argument to sizeof and then later changed. In the best case a refactor-rename operation changes all occurrences and no error is introduced. In the worst case an instance of a sizeof is missed and the compiler complains and you fix it. If the type is changed you are done, no possibility of errors at sizeof statements.

Now imagine the type is the argument to sizeof. If the type of the variable is changed, there is no means other than inspection to find all sizeof relating to that variable. You can search, but you will get hits for all the unrelated uses of sizeof of the same type. If one is missed, you will have a runtime problem due to a size mismatch, which is much more trouble to find.

Comment: For array variables, sizeof(array) will give you the real size of the array. It can be used to calculate the number of elements sizeof(array)/sizeof(element). Note that it won't work for dinamically allocated memory through a pointer.

Comment: Not a plausible argument. In the same way it's possible to claim that if the name of the variable is changed, the sizeof will not require changing if the type is the argument, rather than the variable. Possibility of change for either depends on specific design (and in most cases neither will or should change)

Comment: This answer does not seem to be a "final" solution keeping in mind that it does not cover cases when code logic depends on a typedef rather on a particular variable. You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what Steve says, let me add that sizeof does not evaluate its operand. So you are free to do anything in it. Not only you can use not-yet initialized variables, but you can dereference a null-pointer, call functions not defined but only declared and do any other kind of stuff. I encourage you to always use the expression version for reasons Steve explained greatly.

Also consider that sometimes typenames are really long and unreadable, just think of pointers to functions (especially in C++). Instead of writing `sizeof(my_long_type<weird, stuff>)` you just do `sizeof t`.

Comment: 4 years have passed and the long type names problem in C++ is diminished with `decltype` :)

Comment: This question was never tagged as C++ so what C++ does and doesn't is off-topic. Also, in C specifically, the operand of `sizeof` _is_ evaluated in the special case of VLA. So writing a on-topic answer with the programming language used in the question does matter.

Answer (score 4):

You may see little difference between these:

```
foo **ff = malloc(count * sizeof *ff);
foo **gg = malloc(sizeof(foo*) * count);
```

..but what if the allocation is not nearby to the declaration?  If I come across a line like:

```
ff = realloc(ff, count * sizeof *ff);
```

then I am reasonably confident that the line is correct, without even remembering the type of `ff`.  However, if I see this:

```
ff = realloc(ff, count * sizeof(foo *));
```

then I might be somewhat suspicious, and need to look up the type of `ff` to put my mind at rest.

Comment: This is all just subjective. Now what if the actual declaration was `foo *f` - you'll never spot the bug regardless of style preference, not before you actually dig up the variable declaration.

Answer (score 3):

The lines f and ff are definitely worse than g and gg. `sizeof f` is the pointer size, since f is a point. To make them equivalent, you'd have to write `sizeof *f` (or, for better legibility, `sizeof(*f)`).

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use `sizeof(type)` in memory allocation, but invariably `sizeof(variable)` when using a local or global variable.  Nevertheless, there is wisdom in the advice to use the variable name all the time.

I also had a long discussion (rather animated at times, and it lasted over a period of days -- we ended agreeing to differ on the issue) about whether it is OK to use `sizeof(variable)` or whether it must be `sizeof variable`; that is, does it matter whether parentheses enclose the argument to `sizeof`.  I've never encountered a compiler that witters about `sizeof(variable)`, so I opt for uniformity and always use the parentheses with `sizeof`.  My colleague was equally adamant that parentheses must not be used with variables; that somehow there is/was a valuable distinction between the notation with and without the parentheses.  I've not been persuaded - I don't expect to be persuaded.

On a wholly different tack, a couple of other points about `sizeof`:

- If you're using C99 and VLA - variable-length arrays - then `sizeof(vla)` is not a compile-time constant.  Beware!
- The C pre-processor does not understand `sizeof` which is a nuisance but logical.

Comment: Looks like you've got another askable question here.   My understanding is sizeof is a compile-time thing, even though it kinda looks and acts like a (library) function.  So maybe he wants it to look different.  I don't use it enuf to matter.  Then again I've gotten stares from doing "return(x);"

Comment: I most often use parentheses around the return value.  I know some people are aghast at that, but it works for me.  I'm not confused about either return or sizeof being 'functions'.

Comment: I hate parentheses on return, mostly because it is unnecessary. Having parentheses after sizeof can help readability: malloc(sizeof(*f)*10) is much easier to understand than malloc(sizeof *f*10).

Comment: I seem to recall the rule being ingrained in my head is to not use parenthesis when doing sizeof on a variable.  I think K&R's book is what says to do this, but I agree in practice I think you can always get away with using parenthesis.

Comment: I am using a compiler that requires parenthesis when the parameter is a type (and returns "type name is not allowed" otherwise). I am not sure if this is correct according to the standard, the compiler is supposed to be C99 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the sizeof a variable can have unexpected results.  When the variable is an array, sizeof(array) will return the size of the array, not the size of an individual element or the size of a pointer.  Taking the size of a pointer will return the size of a pointer.  But since arrays are usually represented as pointers when being passed around, things can get confusing.

Comment: While the first line is misleading: there is nothing unexpected in the result, the second sentence is missing from all other answers: sizeof(array) will give you the size of the whole array and not an element. It can be used to compute the number of elements sizeof(array)/sizeof(element)

Comment: @dribeas: yes, hence'#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))' for a variety of possible macro names (ARRAY_SIZE, DIMENSION, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Business logic defines your choice.

1. If your code refers to a particular variable and without this variable your code makes no sense - choose `sizeof(var)`
2. If you code deals with a set of variables with particular type - choose `sizeof(type)`.
   Usually you need this if you have a `typedef` which defines many variables which you process differently based on their type (e.g. serialization). You may not know which of these variables will remain in future code versions so choosing type as an argument is logically correct. Even changing of such `typedef` will not affect your `sizeof` line.