# C programming: Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error

Tags: c, struct, dereference

I have a struct defined as:

```
struct {
 char name[32];
 int  size;
 int  start;
 int  popularity;
} stasher_file;
```

and an array of pointers to those structs:

```
struct stasher_file *files[TOTAL_STORAGE_SIZE];
```

In my code, I'm making a pointer to the struct and setting its members, and adding it to the array:

```
 ...
 struct stasher_file *newFile;
 strncpy(newFile->name, name, 32);
 newFile->size = size;
 newFile->start = first_free;
 newFile->popularity = 0;
 files[num_files] = newFile;
 ...
```

I'm getting the following error:

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

whenever I try to access the members inside `newFile`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, I had the same error, but the problem was that I did not include a specific header file (in a big project).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You haven't defined `struct stasher_file` by your first definition. What you have defined is an *nameless* struct type and a variable `stasher_file` of that type. Since there's no definition for such type as `struct stasher_file` in your code, the compiler complains about incomplete type.

In order to define `struct stasher_file`, you should have done it as follows

```
struct stasher_file {
 char name[32];
 int  size;
 int  start;
 int  popularity;
};
```

Note where the `stasher_file` name is placed in the definition.

Comment: +1 Faster than me, and using `struct stasher_file` instead of a `typedef` is consistent with the OP's use of the type in the example.

Answer (score 13):

You are using the pointer `newFile` without allocating space for it.

```
struct stasher_file *newFile = malloc(sizeof(stasher_file));
```

Also you should put the struct name at the top.  Where you specified stasher_file is to create an instance of that struct.

```
struct stasher_file {
    char name[32];
    int  size;
    int  start;
    int  popularity;
};
```

Comment: How do I allocate space for it?

Comment: I didn't allocate space for the newFile, but changed the definition of stasher_file to be like yours, and the error didn't come up. Do I still need to allocate space?

Comment: @confuseKid: yes you need to allocate space like I gave.  Also make sure to free it when done with it.

Comment: @confuseKid: I recommend that you accept @AndreyT's answer though, he gives a better explanation for the source of the error.

Comment: I believe the actual question asked was "What am I doing wrong?", so this is a more complete answer.

Answer (score 12):

How did you actually define the structure? If

```
struct {
  char name[32];
  int  size;
  int  start;
  int  popularity;
} stasher_file;
```

is to be taken as type definition, it's missing a `typedef`. When written as above, you actually define a variable called `stasher_file`, whose type is some anonymous struct type.

Try

```
typedef struct { ... } stasher_file;
```

(or, as already mentioned by others):

```
struct stasher_file { ... };
```

The latter actually matches your use of the type. The first form would require that you remove the `struct` before variable declarations.

Answer (score 5):

the case above is for a new project.  I hit upon this error while editing a fork of a well established library.

the typedef was included in the file I was editing but the struct wasn't.

The end result being that I was attempting to edit the struct in the wrong place.

If you run into this in a similar way look for other places where the struct is edited and try it there.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting that error is because you've declared your `struct` as:

```
struct {
 char name[32];
 int  size;
 int  start;
 int  popularity;
} stasher_file;
```

This is not declaring a `stasher_file` type.  This is declaring an *anonymous* `struct` type and is creating a global instance named `stasher_file`.

What you intended was:

```
struct stasher_file {
 char name[32];
 int  size;
 int  start;
 int  popularity;
};
```

But note that while Brian R. Bondy's response wasn't correct about your error message, he's right that you're trying to write into the `struct` without having allocated space for it.  If you want an array of pointers to `struct stasher_file` structures, you'll need to call `malloc` to allocate space for each one:

```
struct stasher_file *newFile = malloc(sizeof *newFile);
if (newFile == NULL) {
   /* Failure handling goes here. */
}
strncpy(newFile->name, name, 32);
newFile->size = size;
...
```

(BTW, be careful when using `strncpy`; it's not guaranteed to NUL-terminate.)

Comment: if you have defined structure as typedef struct { ... } stasher_file; then you can use malloc as stasher_file *newFile = malloc(sizeof (stasher_file);

Comment: @katta Yes, but many people consider it to be a better practice to do `T* p = malloc(sizeof *p)` instead.  That way if the type of `p` ever changes, you have to update only its declaration and not the `malloc` sites.  Forgetting to update the `malloc` sites would silently allocate the wrong amount of memory, potentially leading to buffer overflows.

Comment: @katta Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373252/c-sizeof-with-a-type-or-variable

Answer (score 0):

The reason is **you did not declare type `struct stasher_file`, you define a struct variable `stasher_file`
instead.**

In `C`, the declaration of structure:

```c
    struct structure-tag {
        member1
        member2
        ...
    };
```

`structure-tag` is an optional name following the keyword `struct`.
After declaration, you can **define** a variable:

```c
    struct structure-tag var1, *var2;
```

Also, you can do both declaration and definition like:

```c
    struct structure-tag {
        member1
        member2
        ...
    } var1, *var2;
```

So in your case, you could try this:

```c
struct stasher_file {
 char name[32];
 int  size;
 int  start;
 int  popularity;
} *files[TOTAL_STORAGE_SIZE];

struct stasher_file *newFile = malloc(sizeof(struct stasher_file));

... other code ...
```

That's all.