# C: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm getting an error (error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
) with addData->s = s and addData->type = type, and I'm not sure why... it seems like it should work to me (I'm a bit rusty with C, however)

Here's the code:

```
int addSym(char *s, var_type type){
    struct syment* addData=  malloc(sizeof(syment));
    addData->s = s;
    addData->type = type;
```

...

I have syment as

```
typedef struct syment_s {
  char *s;
  int offset;
  var_type type;
  struct syment_s *next;
}*syment;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the double semicolon a typo? `malloc(sizeof(syment));;`

Comment: Yes, sorry about that!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576554/c-programming-dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
typedef struct syment_s {
  char *s;
  int offset;
  var_type type;
  struct syment_s *next;
}*syment;
```

to

```
typedef struct syment_s {
  char *s;
  int offset;
  var_type type;
  struct syment_s *next;
} syment;
```

Pointer overload and this is not Crufts (Pointer is a dog, Crufts is a dog show).

Comment: Thanks!
That and removing the struct in
    struct syment* addData=  malloc(sizeof(syment));
worked, thanks!
I had been told to use the *syment so that I could later use syment*... guess that was wrong!

Comment: Thanks! It says I have to wait a minute before I can (n00b here)

Comment: @winepretzel - Forgot to mention - keep pointers explicit - saves a LOT of hassle in the long run if you know that you are dealing with pointers.