# buildroot toolchain error : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, locale, buildroot

I'm trying to generate a toolchain on my ubuntu 12.04 using buildroot and i'm getting this error

```
TEST_LINK locale/ tst-xlocale2

In file included from tst-xlocale2.c:1:0:

tst-xlocale2.c: In function 'do_test':

../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:315:48: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

 # define __isctype_l(c, type, locale) ((locale)->__ctype_b[(int) (c)] & (__ctype_mask_t) type)

                                                ^
../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:319:28: note: in expansion of macro '__isctype_l'

 #  define __isdigit_l(c,l) __isctype_l((c), _ISdigit, (l))
                            ^
../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:338:26: note: in expansion of macro '__isdigit_l'

 #  define isdigit_l(c,l) __isdigit_l ((c), (l))
                          ^
tst-xlocale2.c:53:16: note: in expansion of macro 'isdigit_l'
```

if ('0' + (TEST (str[n], l) != 0) != RES[n])         \
                    ^
    tst-xlocale2.c:59:3: note: in expansion of macro 'DO_TEST'

```
   DO_TEST (isdigit_l, exd);
   ^
../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:315:48: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

 # define __isctype_l(c, type, locale) ((locale)->__ctype_b[(int) (c)] & (__ctype_mask_t) type)
                                                ^
../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:317:28: note: in expansion of macro '__isctype_l'

 #  define __isalpha_l(c,l) __isctype_l((c), _ISalpha, (l))
                            ^
../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:336:26: note: in expansion of macro '__isalpha_l'

 #  define isalpha_l(c,l) __isalpha_l ((c), (l))
                          ^
tst-xlocale2.c:53:16: note: in expansion of macro 'isalpha_l'

     if ('0' + (TEST (str[n], l) != 0) != RES[n])         \
                ^
tst-xlocale2.c:60:3: note: in expansion of macro 'DO_TEST'

   DO_TEST (isalpha_l, exa);
```

^
    ../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:315:48: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

```
 # define __isctype_l(c, type, locale) ((locale)->__ctype_b[(int) (c)] & (__ctype_mask_t) type)
                                                ^
../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:326:29: note: in expansion of macro '__isctype_l'

 #  define __isxdigit_l(c,l) __isctype_l((c), _ISxdigit, (l))
                             ^
../../install_dir/usr/include/ctype.h:345:27: note: in expansion of macro '__isxdigit_l'

 #  define isxdigit_l(c,l) __isxdigit_l ((c), (l))
                           ^
tst-xlocale2.c:53:16: note: in expansion of macro 'isxdigit_l'

     if ('0' + (TEST (str[n], l) != 0) != RES[n])         \
                ^
```

tst-xlocale2.c:61:3: note: in expansion of macro 'DO_TEST'

```
   DO_TEST (isxdigit_l, exx);
   ^
```

make[2]: *** [tst-xlocale2] Error 1

```
make[1]: *** [_dircompile_locale] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
    build root configuration file 
# Buildroot 2015.02-git-00219-gc5f0e93 Configuration

BR2_ARCH_HAS_ATOMICS=y
BR2_EXTRA_GCC_CONFIG_OPTIONS=""
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_1=y
BR2_GCC_VERSION_4_8_X=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WEBKIT_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_ZCAT="gzip -d -c"
BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY=""
BR2_LARGEFILE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_CONFIG="package/busybox/busybox.config"
BR2_NEEDS_GETTEXT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBNSPR_ARCH_SUPPORT=y
BR2_arm=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GDB=y
BR2_ARM_INSTRUCTIONS_ARM=y
BR2_HOST_DIR="$(BASE_DIR)/host"
BR2_INIT_NONE=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_HAS_NEON=y
BR2_STRIP_EXCLUDE_DIRS=""
BR2_UCLIBC_VERSION_0_9_33=y
BR2_BINUTILS_VERSION_2_22=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_4=y
BR2_BINUTILS_EXTRA_CONFIG_OPTIONS=""
BR2_GCC_SUPPORTS_FINEGRAINEDMTUNE=y
BR2_GNU_MIRROR="http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu"
BR2_GDB_VERSION="7.7.1"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT="ttyAMA0"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ROOT_PASSWD=""
BR2_HG="hg"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_PATCH=""
BR2_ROOTFS_USERS_TABLES=""
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_2=y
BR2_GCC_ENABLE_LIBMUDFLAP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_E2FSPROGS=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_SAME_AS_HEADERS=y
BR2_GCC_NEEDS_MPC=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_IMAGE_TARGET_CUSTOM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY=y
BR2_JLEVEL=0
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION="3.4.105"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_THREADS_NPTL=y
BR2_GCC_VERSION="4.8.3"
BR2_ARM_CPU_MAYBE_HAS_VFPV2=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_GIT_REPO_URL=""
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_MAYBE_HAS_NEON=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ISSUE="Welcome to Buildroot"
BR2_ENDIAN="LITTLE"
BR2_PACKAGE_BOTAN_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_GCC_TARGET_CPU="cortex-a9"
BR2_STRIP_EXCLUDE_FILES=""
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_IMAGE_TARGET_NAME="Image"
BR2_PACKAGE_BDWGC_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_GIT_VERSION=""
BR2_SSH="ssh"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_INET_IPV6=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_GIT_REPO_URL=""
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_REV=0
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_TERM="vt100"
BR2_PTHREADS_NATIVE=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_0=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_BAUDRATE="115200"
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_RESBLKS=0
BR2_BZCAT="bzcat"
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_GEN=2
BR2_UCLIBC_ARM_BX=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_HAS_THUMB2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_INODES=0
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_SHADOW_PASSWORDS=y
BR2_UCLIBC_INSTALL_TEST_SUITE=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST="3.4"
BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_3_4=y
BR2_SYSTEM_BIN_SH="/bin/busybox"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_USES_UCLIBC=y
BR2_STRIP_strip=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_2r0=y
BR2_KERNEL_MIRROR="https://www.kernel.org/pub"
BR2_GCC_ENABLE_TLS=y
BR2_cortex_a9=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="/home/doha/buildroot/configs/arm_foundationv8_defconfig"
BR2_GDB_VERSION_7_7=y
BR2_TARGET_LDFLAGS="y"
BR2_ARM_SOFT_FLOAT=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_CXX=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_INET_RPC=y
BR2_SOFT_FLOAT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GETTEXT=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_MAYBE_HAS_VFPV3=y
BR2_GCC_ENABLE_OPENMP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_CANFESTIVAL_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_SYSTEM_BIN_SH_BUSYBOX=y
BR2_PRIMARY_SITE=""
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT=""
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_BLOCKS=0
BR2_LOCALFILES="cp"
BR2_GIT="git"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_UCLIBC=y
BR2_UCLIBC_INSTALL_UTILS=y
BR2_GLOBAL_PATCH_DIR=""
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_NONE=y
BR2_CVS="cvs"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_WCHAR=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_BAUDRATE_115200=y
BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_TABLE="system/device_table.txt"
BR2_ARCH="arm"
BR2_GCC_SUPPORTS_GRAPHITE=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_3=y
BR2_TAR_OPTIONS=""
BR2_UCLIBC_CONFIG="package/uclibc/uClibc-0.9.33.config"
BR2_OPTIMIZE_S=y
BR2_ARM_EABI=y
BR2_BZR="bzr"
BR2_INSTALL_LIBSTDCPP=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_OPTIONS=""
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBATOMIC_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_PASSWD_MD5=y
BR2_GCC_TARGET_FLOAT_ABI="soft"
BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_CREATION_DYNAMIC_DEVTMPFS=y
BR2_XZCAT="xzcat"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_LIBC="uclibc"
BR2_ARM_INSTRUCTIONS_ARM_CHOICE=y
BR2_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_PASSWD_METHOD="md5"
BR2_SCP="scp"
BR2_BINUTILS_VERSION="2.22"
BR2_PACKAGE_MAKE=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_VENDOR="buildroot"
BR2_ECLIPSE_REGISTER=y
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT=""
BR2_LUAROCKS_MIRROR="http://rocks.moonscript.org"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_LARGEFILE=y
BR2_INET_IPV6=y
BR2_USE_WCHAR=y
BR2_WGET="wget --passive-ftp -nd -t 3"
BR2_USE_MMU=y
BR2_UCLIBC_TARGET_ARCH="arm"
BR2_PACKAGE_OVERRIDE_FILE="$(CONFIG_DIR)/local.mk"
BR2_TARGET_OPTIMIZATION="y"
BR2_DL_DIR="$(TOPDIR)/dl"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_HOSTNAME="buildroot"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_THREADS=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_GIT_VERSION=""
BR2_PACKAGE_SYSTEMD_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBBSD_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_UCLIBC_VERSION_STRING="0.9.33.2"
BR2_CPAN_MIRROR="http://cpan.metacpan.org"
BR2_PACKAGE_MONO_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_SVN="svn"
BR2_GCC_TARGET_ABI="aapcs-linux"
BR2_PACKAGE_XBMC_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_REMOUNT_ROOTFS_RW=y
BR2_GCC_TARGET_MODE="arm"
BR2_ARM_CPU_ARMV7A=y
BR2_DEFCONFIG="$(CONFIG_DIR)/defconfig"
BR2_PACKAGE_GOOGLE_BREAKPAD_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_UCLIBC=y
BR2_ARM_ENABLE_NEON=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_2=y
BR2_GCC_ENABLE_GRAPHITE=y
BR2_ROOTFS_SKELETON_DEFAULT=y
BR2_DEFAULT_KERNEL_HEADERS="3.4.105"
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENEXT2FS=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_IMAGE_NAME=""
BR2_PACKAGE_QT5_JSCORE_AVAILABLE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_TZDATA_ZONELIST=""
BR2_BACKUP_SITE="http://sources.buildroot.net"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_NATIVE_RPC=y
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576554/c-programming-dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type-error

Comment: Are you really using Buildroot as Buildroot made available by http://buildroot.org ? If so, can you specify which version you're using, and post your Buildroot .config file?

Comment: @ThomasPetazzoni I added the buildroot configuration to the question 
 Buildroot 2015.02-git-00219-gc5f0e93

Comment: @Doha your Buildroot configuration file looks really weird, options are sorted in a strange way. How did you generate it? Please run "make savedefconfig" and post the contents of the "defconfig" file, unchanged. Thanks!