# sizeof operator and structs

Tags: c, sizeof

```
struct s  
{  
    int i;  
    char * c;  
} *obj;
obj = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
```

Say for example we have a struct as defined above (or any struct in general, i just wrote the above one for the sake of example).

Then, what is better when using the sizeof operator

sizeof(struct s) or sizeof(*obj) ?

I prefer the first one since it makes more sense to me (clearly tells us that we're allocating memory for an object of struct s)

Also, using the second one can introduce logical errors (like the usual 'forgetting to dereference the pointer')

Can the first one cause any problems? 
I haven't had problems with it yet but just wanted to know whether what i'm doing is proper or not.

If so, can you please provide an example of where it can fail?

Comment: I don't know why this is voted as "not constructive".  This is a good question.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["C" sizeof with a type or variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373252/c-sizeof-with-a-type-or-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either **may** be used.

`sizeof(*obj)` **should** always be used, though, because if the type of `obj` ever changes, this will still work.  With `sizeof(struct s)`, you will have a latent bug.

Comment: Yes, I see the flaw in my method. Changing the struct name would at least spit out errors but changing the type would be disastrous if not taken care of. I think i'll stick to the objects from now on. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

> Then, what is better when using the sizeof operator
>
> sizeof(struct s) or sizeof(*obj) ?

It's a matter of preference.

I prefer `sizeof(*obj)`. If I later change the type of `obj` (say, `struct s2`), `sizeof(struct s)` will be out of date.

Comment: I prefer `sizeof(*obj)` because, when used with a variable (rather than a type), the parentheses are optional (as `sizeof` is an operator, not a function), and I think `sizeof *obj` looks rather nice.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer the `sizeof(struct s)` despite if the structures name changes the code is out of date. My philosophy is thaat if the structure changes it is best to revist the code that uses it just to be on the safe side.

Comment: -1: `sizeof(*obj)` should always be preferred.  If the *type* of `obj` ever changes, you will have a silent bug with `sizeof(struct s)`.