# Allocating a block of memory with malloc()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I've got a rather unusual question.
I've seen two variants of passing arguments to malloc. Let's say we've got:

`int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizex * sizeof(*arr));`

Some people say that using `sizeof(*arr)` is bad and you should use `sizeof(int)` (in this example) instead.
Could you explain what's the difference and what's better to use?

Comment: It's not really unusual: ["C" sizeof with a type or variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373252/c-sizeof-with-a-type-or-variable)

Comment: If you ever need to change from `int` to, say, `float`, you wouldn't have to change much if you use first technique (`sizeof(*arr)`). Also, don't cast your `malloc`.

Comment: Don't cast the return from `malloc()`, either.

Comment: Just for fun, you can even write `int *arr = malloc(sizex * sizeof(arr[100]));`

Comment: @pmg, is `sizeof (arr[0])` zero?

Comment: @pmg, `arr` is an pointer, not a type. `Sizeof (arr[100])` returns the size of the 100th element of `arr`, which is the same as `sizeof (arr[0])` or `sizeof (*arr)`.

Comment: Oops .. I misread your comments, my bad. Sorry. You're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Both allocate the same amount of memory -

```
int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizex * sizeof(*arr));
// equivalent to
int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizex * sizeof(int));
```

However, there are some things to note.

1. You should not cast the result of `malloc`. It's not useful and can actually cause problems if you forget to include the header `stdlib.h` which contains its prototype. Please read this - [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1809377)
2. I prefer the first version above because there's no repetition of the type information. Also, it's more maintainable in the sense that if you change the type, then you need to change it only once where as in the second case, you need to change it in two places.

It should be noted that `sizeof` needs parentheses for its operand only when it's a type. Therefore, it can be written more succinctly as

```
int *arr = malloc(sizex * sizeof *arr); 
// equivalent to
int *arr = malloc(sizex * sizeof(*arr));  // preferred way
```

Comment: I like to think of parenthesis for `sizeof` as it being the type that needs parenthesis (like it was a cast).

Comment: @pmg, this is actually how it's described in the standard.

Comment: @pmg I think it's a personal choice. Doing away with a pair of parentheses makes the code a bit cleaner, I think but then it's me.

Comment: I don't like the redundant parenthesis. What I mean is that the parenthesis belong to the type, not to the operator.

Comment: @pmg true. now I think the parentheses might make the code more readable avoiding potential confusion. I'll include it but I need to be consistent with the style.