# C - predicting runtime ram usage for a simple application

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, ram

Suppose I have the following program - that take a number (eg 10M) from the command line, creates an array of this size, populates it with random integers, hangs around for 15 seconds and then quits. How much RAM should it take up? (Given an input of 10M)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("running\n");
  long long size = atoi(argv[1]);
  printf("%lld\n", size);
  int *myArray = malloc(size * sizeof *myArray);
  printf("allocated array\n");
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (long long i=0;i<size;i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      printf("first iteration\n");
    }
    int r = rand();
    myArray[i] = r;
  }
  printf("Allocated\n");
  sleep(15);
  printf("Done\n");
}
```

Given the input

```
./a.out 10000000
```

This (in the Mac Activity Monitor) takes up 38.4M.

My question is: **Is there a way to predict the RAM usage of a simple C application given these parameters?** ie an array of 10M integers.

Comment: I think this equation should show about 99% of all ram in bytes. `size * sizeof *myArray`

Comment: P.S.> how can you do `sizeof *myArray` before the myArray is even initialized? makes no sense.

Comment: What you were looking for is `malloc(size * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @SSpoke This use of `sizeof` is both legal and recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/q/373252/509868

Comment: @anatolyg I guess it works because the malloc asm is executed after myArray? it still doesn't look good on the eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have 32 bit (4 byte) integers on your system.

10 million integers take 10 million * 4 = 40 million bytes.

40 million bytes = 40000000/1024/1024 = 38.15MB, which is close to what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot predict it *precisely* because of multiple factors including the size of the code in memory, as well as alignment, but for this simple application, you can get pretty close, as Joachim's answer pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 32-bit machine, each `int` takes 4 bytes, so an array of 10M ints will use about 40 MB for the array you're allocating. In addition, it uses memory for the code of the program itself, and all the libraries that it links with.

However, this is all *virtual* memory. The amount of RAM that it uses depends on what it's doing. If it allocates an array but never uses it, the array may never be loaded into RAM at all. Or after it has used it, some parts may be paged out, so the array may never be all in memory at once. The way that virtual memory is reflected in real RAM use can be hard to predict, if there's enough going on on your system that it can't keep every program's memory in RAM at the same time.