# memcpy start index really needed?

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

The question is when we are copying any Byte array using `memcpy()`, shall we explicitly declare the starting (0 th) index for the destination buffer or simple mentioning it would suffice. Let me show the examples what I'm talking about. Provided that we are trying to copy source buffer to starting of the destination buffer.

```
BYTE *pucInputData; // we have some data here
BYTE ucOutputData[20] = {0};
```

**Code 1**

```
memcpy((void*)&ucOutputData, (void*)pucInputData, 20);
```

**Code 2**

```
memcpy((void*)&ucOutputData[0], (void*)pucInputData, 20);
```

Comment: You never need to cast an object pointer (i.e. not a function pointer) *into* a `void*`. It's more likely to hide problems than to solve any.

Comment: The address of an array converted to `void*` is the same as the address of its initial element converted to `void*`, so both expressions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, both of your examples are sub-optimal.

Remember that all data pointers in C convert to/from `void *` (which is the type of the first argument to `memcpy()`) without loss of information and that no cast is necessary to do so.

Also remember that the name of an array evaluates to the address of the first element in many contexts, such as here.

Also remember to use `sizeof` when you can, never introduce a literal constant when you don't have to.

So, the copy should just be:

```
memcpy(ucOutputData, pucInputData, sizeof ucOutputData);
```

Note that we use `sizeof` without parentheses, it's not a function. Also we use it on the *destination* buffer, which seems the safer choice.

Comment: could you please tell more about parentheses use on sizeof. General I use parentheses always while using sizeof operator.

Comment: @hypheni The parentheses are only needed when the argument is a type name, i.e. `sizeof (int)`. That's because in that case, the argument is a cast expression, and they have that syntax. Otherwise no parentheses are needed.

Comment: @hypheni Although `sizeof(type)` is unusual and unreliable, using parentheses with type names as well is free and foolproof. Pretty worth for two chars, imo.

Comment: @black What do you mean with "unusual and unreliable"?

Comment: @gurka let `int x;`, it's better to use `sizeof(x)` or `sizeof x` rather than `sizeof(int)` because, if you happen to change the type of `x`, the former version will adapt to that whilst the latter won't therefore avoiding potential devious errors.

Comment: @black Aha, yes that makes sense. But I guess that I still need it for cases like: `int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));` and `struct Foo* x = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo));`, etc. So I wouldn't want to call `sizeof(type)` unusual nor unreliable, but your comment explained what you meant :)

Comment: @gurka, Even in that case, I'd prefer `struct foo *x = malloc(sizeof(some_already_declared_foo));` for the same reasons. For "unusual" I mean that, unless you can't otherwise (like you've no `struct foo` yet declared), the other version is just better and you'd tendentiously find that one indeed. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373252/c-sizeof-with-a-type-or-variable) it's explained a little more in depth.

Comment: @black According to that question and its answers/comments you should be able to do: `struct Foo *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));`. So you'll get the sizeof whats x is pointing to (i.e. a `struct Foo`). That's nice.

Comment: Yes, `struct Foo *x = malloc(sizeof *x);` is what I would recommend. It's good not to repeat things, that can introduce errors.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, considering this a C code snippet, and `ucOutputData` is an array

- `memcpy(ucOutputData, pucInputData, 20);`
- `memcpy(&ucOutputData[0], pucInputData, 20);`

both are **same** and can be used Interchangeably. The name of the array essentially gives you the address of the first element in the array.

Now, as per the very useful discussion in below comments, it is worthy to mention, that

```
memcpy(&ucOutputData, pucInputData, 20);
```

will also do the job here, but there is a *fundamental difference* between the usage of *array name* and *address of array name*. Considering the example in the question,  for a definition like `BYTE ucOutputData[20]`,

- `ucOutputData` points to the address of the first element of an array of 20 `BYTE`s.
- `&ucOutputData` is a pointer to an array of 20 `BYTE`s.

So, they are of different type and C respects the type of the variable. Hence, to avoid any possible misuse and misconception, the recommended and safe way to use this is either of the the first two expressions.

FWIW, the cast(s) here is(are) really not needed. Any pointer type can be implicitly ansd safely be converted to `void *` in C.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79443/discussion-on-answer-by-sourav-ghosh-memcpy-start-index-really-needed).

Answer (score 2):

Since an expression `&array[0]` is the same as `array`, and because any pointer can be implicitly converted to `void*`, you should do this instead:

```
memcpy(ucOutputData, pucInputData, 20);
```

Moreover, since you are writing over the entire `ucOutputData`, you do not need to zero out its content, so it's OK to drop the initializer:

```
BYTE ucOutputData[20]; // no "= {0}" part
```

Answer (score 1):

A native array can decay to a pointer without conversion, so in the snippet below, the three assignments to `p` all result in the same value; `p` will point to the beginning of the array. No explicit cast is needed because casting to `void*` is implicit.

```
typedef char BYTE;
BYTE ucOutputData[20] = {0};

void *p = &ucOutputData;
p = ucOutputData;
p = &ucOutputData[0];
```