# How to implement cs50's pset3 frequency and understand notes.c

Tags: c, cs50

I have few questions about cs50's music.

1) There is a line `for (int i = 0, n = sizeof(NOTES) / sizeof(string); i < n; i++)` in `notes.c`. What means sizeof(**string**)? I can understand sizeof(NOTES), here NOTES is an array of strings. But what **string** meant in sezeof(**string**)? I can't get it.

2) Here is my implementation of "frequency":

```
int frequency(string note)
{
    char N[2];
    int octave;
       //parsing the string into a note...
    strncpy(N, note, (strlen(note) - 1));
    //...and its octave
    octave = note[strlen(note) - 1] - '0';
    //add semitones
    int semitone;
    if (strcmp(N, "C") == 0)
        semitone = 1;
    if (strcmp(N, "C#") == 0 || strcmp(N, "Db") == 0)
        semitone = 2;
    if (strcmp(N, "D") == 0)
        semitone = 3;
    if (strcmp(N, "D#") == 0 || strcmp(N, "Eb") == 0)
        semitone = 4;
    if (strcmp(N, "E") == 0)
        semitone = 5;
    if (strcmp(N, "F") == 0)
        semitone = 6;
    if (strcmp(N, "F#") == 0 || strcmp(N, "Gb") == 0)
        semitone = 7;
    if (strcmp(N, "G") == 0)
        semitone = 8;
    if (strcmp(N, "G#") == 0 || strcmp(N, "Ab") == 0)
        semitone = 9;
    if (strcmp(N, "A") == 0)
        semitone = 10;
    if (strcmp(N, "A#") == 0 || strcmp(N, "Bb") == 0)
        semitone = 11;
    if (strcmp(N, "B") == 0)
        semitone = 12;
    //calculate freq: semitones
    float freq = 440 * (powf(2, (semitone -10) / (float)12));
    //calculate freq: multiply by num of octaves
    return round(freq * (powf(2, octave - 4)));
}
```

And output after ./notes is:

```
 C4: 262
C#4: 922746880
 D4: 294
helpers.c:55:12: runtime error: value 5.85908e+09 is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'
D#4: -2147483648
 E4: 330
 F4: 349
F#4: -2147483648
 G4: 392
G#4: -2147483648
 A4: 440
A#4: -2147483648
 B4: 494
```

Code itself works, but it doesn't work in notes.c.

Please, help me to understand what's wrong.

Comment: It means (a) someone doesn't understand how `sizeof` works, and (b) once again, someone was bit by the dreadfully hideous proliferation of `cs50.h` and its type alias of `typedef char *string;`. Fyi, `note` had better be a single-character string, and even then, it will leave `N` with no terminating nullchar after that `strncpy`. Therefore, any `strxxx` call expecting a terminator (they nearly all do) is not going to function expectedly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["C" sizeof with a type or variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373252/c-sizeof-with-a-type-or-variable)

Comment: Perhaps you could ask in https://cs50.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK, it could be solved like in my answer. But is it possible to solve this problem using recursion? I can't make a connection between the lecture (about sorting algorithms and recursion) and the problem set.

Comment: In CS50 code, `sizeof(string)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)` thanks to a typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is <strike>a mistake</strike><sup>1</sup> an alias for the type `char *` (pointer to `char`).  C does not have an actual "string" data type; strings are represented as sequences of character values followed by a 0-valued terminator.  For example, the string `"hello"` is represented by the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.  That terminating 0 is important - without it, various library routines like `strcpy` and `strlen` and `printf` won't recognize the sequence as a string.

Strings are stored in arrays of `char`.  Under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "array of `char`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `char`" (`char *`).  So, most of the time, we're dealing with `char *` expressions when we're dealing with strings.

This does not, however, mean that a `char *` *is* a string.  A `char *` may point to the beginning of a string (that is, a zero-terminated sequence of character values), or it may point to the beginning of a sequence of character values that *isn't* a string, or it may point to a single character that isn't part of a larger sequence.

With that rant out of the way...

since `string == char *`, `sizeof (string) == sizeof (char *)`, which is the number of bytes<sup>2</sup> in a `char *`. `NOTES` is obviously an array of `char *`, so `sizeof(NOTES)` is the number of bytes in the `NOTES` array.  Dividing `sizeof(NOTES)` by `sizeof(string)` gives us the number of elements in the `NOTES` array.

---

1. The `cs50.h` header file creates the `string` typedef, I guess to abstract away C's, uh, *unique* string and array semantics.  Unfortunately, this has led to much confusion among CS50 students.  I, personally, consider it a blunder by the people who created the CS50 curriculum.

   Technically, "storage units", but a storage unit effectively is a byte.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Now it looks and works better.

```
//parsing the string into a note...
    char N = note[0];
    //...and its octave
    int octave = note[strlen(note) - 1] - '0';
    //add semitones
    int semitone;
    if (N == 'C')
        semitone = 1;
    if (N == 'D')
        semitone = 3;
    if (N == 'E')
        semitone = 5;
    if (N == 'F')
        semitone = 6;
    if (N == 'G')
        semitone = 8;
    if (N == 'A')
        semitone = 10;
    if (N == 'B')
        semitone = 12;
    //add accidentals
    if (note[1] == '#')
        semitone ++;
    if (note[1] == 'b')
        semitone --;
    //calculate freq: semitones
    float freq = 440 * (powf(2, (semitone - 10) / (float)12));
    //calculate freq: multiply by num of octaves
    return round(freq * (powf(2, octave - 4)));
```

And I will read more about sizeof.

Comment: To really make this an answer, highlight what you chaneged and why.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to break this down a bit.

You get the from your array:

```
   int octave = note[strlen(note) - 1];
```

you will get the ASCII value of the last string as an integer. To convert it to the right number you need to 'shift through' the ASCII table.

```
   octave -= 48; // Adjust ASCII to int value
```

Because char 0 = ASCII 48 you can do it in one step.

```
   int octave = note[strlen(note) - 1] - '0';
```

Note that this works when you want to get back an integer represented as alpha in your array.
If you want to get back a string (aka char *) from your array you need to do it a bit differently. The key is that even a single character long string should end with a \0

So, now you want to get the tone:

```
    char N[2];
    N[0] = note[0];
    N[1] = '\0';
```

Note the difference between the above and this:

```
    char N = note[0];
```