# How to keep space after `sizeof`?

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

Basically the title. I want my spacing rules to produce this:

```cpp
#define MACRO_FOO(x) x
MACRO_FOO(2)
int foo(int x);
foo(2);

if (condition) {
    ...
}
while (false) {
    ...
}
sizeof (int)
```

By default, clang-format puts `sizeof` in the first group, not the second. Is there any way to leave a space after the word `sizeof`?

The main reason I have for spacing it like that is expressions such as the following:

```c
sizeof buffer / sizeof (int)
```

where having a space after the first `sizeof` but not the second feels rather inconsistent.

Comment: I think mixing `sizeof` with and without parentheses is on its own inconsistent.

Comment: You should never use `sizeof buffer / sizeof (int)`, use `::std::size` instead.

Comment: In general you should prefer using `sizeof expr`, which is safer than `sizeof (Type)`. For example: `sizeof buffer / sizeof buffer[0]`.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind the operand to `sizeof` may be an expression (such as `buffer`) or a type cast (such as `(int)`); I'm sure I've seen it formatted like this before, though I couldn't say where. @user7860670 I'm using C++14, and `std::size` is a C++17 function.

Comment: There were plenty of alternatives for `std::size` available prior to C++17. It is a trivial function to implement.

Comment: This is tagged as both C++ and C.  The answer to this question depends on which.  In C, I always use parentheses with `sizeof`, with no space, regardless of whether I'm using a type or an expression.  E.g. `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(x+2)`, etc.  Given that a `sizeof` reference can be used in an expression, I find any spaces between the `sizeof` and its operand to be less clear, hence why I always use parentheses, which eliminate the need for such a space.  In C++, there may be a different answer.

Comment: @Bbrk24 putting spaces in front of parenthesis may lead either to inconsistently looking or  unreadable code, depending on code base nature. We had someone reformatting our project like that, we still groan on lines like: `if ( !isNum || ( it.value ().toDouble () < params.value ( it.key () ).min || it.value ().toDouble () > params.value ( it.key () ).max ) )`

Comment: After trying this myself, it is notable that clang-format reformats `sizeof (x + y)` to `sizeof(x + y)`, so it could still be a (rare) problem even for idiomatically-written code. (I'd personally prefer the space.) Looking over https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html, I see no relevant flags for `SpaceBeforeParensOptions`, no relevant `...SpaceAfter...` options, and nothing that mentions `sizeof`.  Therefore I think it's simply currently not possible to configure clang-format to always put a space after `sizeof`.  Perhaps file an issue.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I don't think anybody's talking about putting spaces before *all* parentheses.  The request here is to always put a space after `sizeof` so that `sizeof x` and `sizeof (x)` are treated consistently.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for verifying. Could you put that as an answer rather than leaving it in the comments?

Comment: @jamesdlin an example where it would look misleading: `sizeof (a)*p` Is it `sizeof` of expression `(a)*p` or `sizeof` of type `a` multiplied by `p`? Yes, by operator precedence  it always the latter, but spacing makes people "fast-read" it as the former and then re-read (subconsciously in some cases).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `sizeof a*p` would be just as misleading, unless you're also arguing for always using parentheses with `sizeof`.  Regardless, such code should be frowned upon for not instead being `p * sizeof a`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I guess Clang format would put spaces around that `*` operator anyway, making it look less misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking over https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html, I see:

- No relevant flags for `SpaceBeforeParensOptions`.
- No relevant `...SpaceAfter...` options.
- Nothing that mentions `sizeof`.

Therefore, I think it's simply currently not possible to configure clang-format to always put a space after `sizeof`.

(While I strongly discourage the use of `sizeof (Type)` because [it's less safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373252/), I personally do prefer having a space after `sizeof` so that `sizeof expr` and `sizeof (expr)` are treated consistently and so that `sizeof` is more obviously a language construct and not a function (or function-like macro) call.  Consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues).)

Comment: "While I strongly discourage the use of sizeof (Type)" You keep saying this but provide no argument why. Unlike (in)famously, Linus Torvalds: https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/7/11/103

Comment: @Lundin Okay, updated.

Comment: The link you provided is mostly about why `sizeof(var)` is preferred over `sizeof(int)`. It doesn't explain why `sizeof var` should be preferred over `sizeof (var)`. And well, I think this is a completely subjective style matter with no clear industry consensus (and Torvalds is by no means a C guru or authoritative source), so maybe SO isn't the best place for it.

Comment: @Lundin My point was never that `sizeof var` should be preferred over `sizeof (var)`, which I agree is subjective and which I don't personally have much opinion about.  I only meant to discourage `sizeof (Type)`.

Comment: Well you did so in comments above, "In general you should prefer using sizeof expr, which is safer than sizeof (Type)". And well, `sizeof (var)` and `sizeof (Type)` is _also_ a subjective style argument. I've discussed the various pros and cons here [How to properly use malloc?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285898/285910#answer-285910) (questions about coding style are on-topic at Codidact unlike SO/SE, so those interested in such can post there instead).

Comment: @Lundin Again, that wasn't my intended point.  I recommended `sizeof expr` over `sizeof (Type)` because 1. It's generally safer; 2. No parentheses for `sizeof expr` matched OP's existing style; 3. No parentheses for `sizeof expr` would avoid the consistency problem that the OP complained about.  I did not intend to make any judgment about `sizeof expr` vs. `sizeof (expr)`.